# Update to Node 9 Results in Minification

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, minify

I hope you could help me to figure this out. I have a project that uses Webpack and React. If I update Node from v. 6 to 9, the code gets minified. If I downgrade Node back to v. 6, everything as it is supposed to be. I was wondering why could it happen? As I understand, minification is something that should happen on demand. Does Node 9 enforce somehow minification? 
Here are my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "tgc-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "table-grid-ui",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require test/helpers/browser.js test/*/*.spec.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "ssh://git@stash.idalko.com:7999/ip/tgc-ui.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "table",
    "grid",
    "ui"
  ],
  "author": "idalko",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@atlaskit/banner": "^2.4.2",
    "@atlaskit/button": "^5.4.8",
    "@atlaskit/checkbox": "^1.0.0",
    "@atlaskit/dynamic-table": "^7.2.0",
    "@atlaskit/field-text": "^4.1.2",
    "@atlaskit/flag": "^6.1.8",
    "@atlaskit/icon": "^7.0.0",
    "@atlaskit/inline-edit": "^4.5.6",
    "@atlaskit/inline-message": "^3.0.4",
    "@atlaskit/input": "^1.1.2",
    "@atlaskit/lozenge": "^3.4.2",
    "@atlaskit/modal-dialog": "^3.0.2",
    "@atlaskit/multi-select": "^7.1.7",
    "@atlaskit/single-select": "^3.0.0",
    "@atlaskit/spinner": "^2.2.3",
    "@atlaskit/tabs": "^2.0.0",
    "@atlaskit/tooltip": "^6.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "brace": "^0.11.0",
    "browser-locale": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-ace": "^5.8.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.0",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.7.2",
    "react-autosize-textarea": "^0.4.9",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-data-grid": "^2.0.53",
    "react-data-grid-addons": "^2.0.53",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.53.0",
    "react-datetime": "^2.10.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-file-reader-input": "^1.1.4",
    "react-keybinding-component": "^0.5.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.6.1",
    "string-hash": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^1.4.6",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "yarn": "^0.27.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-require": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "jsdom": "^11.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.4",
    "sinon": "^2.3.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "uglify-js": "^3.0.23",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.6",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

and webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

var path = require('path'),
    jsxPath  = 'src',
    jsPath = 'dist/lib',
    srcPath = path.join(__dirname, jsxPath);

var isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
var uiVersion = (process.env.CI_VERSION === '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT') ? '' : `_${process.env.CI_VERSION}`;

var service = {
    jiracloud: './custom_modules/CloudUtilityService.jsx'
}[process.env.APP_ENV];

function getPlugins() {
    var plugins = [];

    plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'CI_VERSION': JSON.stringify(process.env.CI_VERSION),
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            'APP_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.APP_ENV)
        }
    }));

    if (isProd) {
        plugins.push(new UglifyJSPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true,
                conditionals: true,
                unused: true,
                comparisons: true,
                sequences: true,
                dead_code: true,
                evaluate: true,
                if_return: true,
                join_vars: true
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            }
        }));
    }

    return plugins;
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        errorLicense: [path.join(srcPath, 'license/ErrorLicense.jsx')],
        ducketConfiguration: [path.join(srcPath, 'ducketconfig/DucketConfig.jsx')],
        dataSourceConfiguration: [path.join(srcPath, 'datasource/DataSourcesPage.jsx')],
        ducket: [path.join(srcPath, 'grid/Grid.jsx')],
        serviceDesk: [path.join(srcPath, 'adjustment/servicedesk/ServiceDesk.jsx')],
        searchHelp: [path.join(srcPath, 'search/SearchHelp.jsx')]
    },
    output: {
        //path:path.resolve(__dirname, jsPath),
       path:path.resolve(__dirname, "../tgc/public/javascript"),
        filename: `[name]${uiVersion}.js`
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders:['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)(\?\S*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000@name=[name][ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'styled-components': path.resolve('./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.es.js'),
            'utility-service': path.resolve(service)
        }
    },
    plugins: getPlugins()
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Iev--

Answer (score 0):

Node does never enforce minification, this piece of code in your webpack configuration is:

```
if (isProd) {
    plugins.push(new UglifyJSPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false,
            screw_ie8: true,
            conditionals: true,
            unused: true,
            comparisons: true,
            sequences: true,
            dead_code: true,
            evaluate: true,
            if_return: true,
            join_vars: true
        },
        output: {
            comments: false
        }
    }));
}
```

This probably wasn't working on an older version of node because your devDependencies are for uglify@3 which might require node.js > v6

Comment: Thank you for reply! I am afraid that this is no the case. Uglify works as expected with v. 6.10. I also tried to remove the plugin, however, the minification persisted. When I install Node v. 7 and 8, they seem to work just fine. So far, I could find the problem only with Node v. 9... Trying different minor versions now.

Comment: Uglify is the only minifier in your dependencies. Maybe your code is being transpiled by babel? Can you show me an example of the output code? And what command do you use to initialize your app?

Comment: (function(a,b,c){function bc(b){if(!U {P=b,_(),y=a(P),Q=0,K.rel!=="nofollow"&&(y=a("."+g)... I am using simple 'webpack' as command without any parameters. I played yesterday with different versions of Node, I also deleted and reinstalled all node modules, and at some point everything started to work as expected on Node 9 as well. And now, I could not reproduce the problem anymore. That is strange, because I didn't change any configurations... Could it happen because one of the modules was butchered?